# How can I ask a professor I've had as an undergrad for a recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am currently a Masters student adn I'm applying for an abroad research program which requires two letters of recommendation. This professor already wrote my recommendation to get into grad school (he was my professor during undergrad) and I want him to resubmit the letter to my research program. I wanted to know if this would be an okay email to send:

"Hi Professor __,

I hope you're doing well! I wanted to reach out to you because I'm currently enrolled in a Masters Program and I found out a few days ago about a research program called ____ in Germany. I was hoping to apply for it for this summer, and I wanted to know if you would resubmit my letter of recommendation (the one which you wrote last year)? The deadline for the application is ____. Sorry for such a last minute notice, I only recently found out about this program. I completely understand if it wouldn't be doable or if you don't have the prior recommendation, no worries if that's the case! Thanks again!

Best,

---

"

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly fine if you just need a letter resubmitted, but often the best letters are tailored to particular opportunities - i.e., a letter talking about how well-suited user130306 is for Arbitrary Masters Program is going to look funny when you are reading that letter as a committee member for Abroad Research Program.

I would suggest acknowledging in your email that the recommender *may need to write a new letter* (though the previous one may be suitable as a draft) and ask if they are willing to do so. Implying that they can just resubmit a previous letter might be perceived as (weakly) rude or not understanding what recommendation letters entail.

Also I presume your second letter will come from someone at your current institution? It's certainly okay to use a previous recommender when you have not spent much time at your new institution, but ideally letters come from people who can best describe the *current you*.